# Replace primary menu with secondary on all pages except front page in WordPress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I want to display my primary menu only on front-page.php (which is my home page), and to display secondary menu on all other pages except my home page.

I've registered primary and secondary menu in my functions.php like this:

```
register_nav_menus( array(
    'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'nwd' ),
    'secondary' => __( 'Secondary Menu', 'nwd'),
) );
```

I'm loading my primary menu in my header.php like this (I'm using wp_navwalker for my menu):

```
            <div class=""> <!-- Menu -->
                <nav class="main-menu navbar-inverse col-md-offset-2 col-md-6" role="banner">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                      <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      </button>
                    </div>

                        <?php
                            wp_nav_menu( array(
                                'menu'              => 'primary',
                                'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                                'depth'             => 1,
                                'container'         => 'nav',
                                'container_class'   => 'navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse collapse',
                                'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                                'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav no-gutter cl-effect-4',
                                'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                                'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                            );
                        ?>
                </nav>      
            </div> <!-- End menu -->
```

I've tried using [this solution](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/replace-navigation-menu-with-custom-menu-when-using-custom-page-template?replies=2) from WordPress forums but I didn't manage to do what I want.

Any suggestions?

All the help is GREATLY appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can use `is_front_page()` to do the check and provide the proper menu:

```
<?php
    $menu_slug = is_front_page() ? 'primary' : 'secondary';

     wp_nav_menu( array(
         'menu'              => $menu_slug,
         'theme_location'    => $menu_slug,
         'depth'             => 1,
         'container'         => 'nav',
         'container_class'   => 'navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse collapse',
         'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
         'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav no-gutter cl-effect-4',
         'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
         'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
     );
?>
```

Comment: I'm not getting the result that I need. Instead I'm getting "ADD A MENU" message in my header on all pages (home, and all others). Like I did not create any menus. Any other suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully did what I wanted with the help of conditional statement `if (is_front_page())` .

Here is my code for the menu that I've used in the header.php. Hope this will be helpful to someone also:

```
<?php

                                    if (is_front_page()){
                                              wp_nav_menu( array(
                                                'menu'              => 'primary',
                                                'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                                                'depth'             => 1,
                                                'container'         => 'nav',
                                                'container_class'   => 'navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse collapse',
                                                'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                                                'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav no-gutter cl-effect-4',
                                                'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                                                'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                                );
                                                    } else {
                                                        wp_nav_menu( array(
                                                'menu'              => 'secondary',
                                                'theme_location'    => 'secondary',
                                                'depth'             => 1,
                                                'container'         => 'nav',
                                                'container_class'   => 'navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse collapse',
                                                'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                                                'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav no-gutter cl-effect-4',
                                                'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                                                'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                                            );
                                                }


                            ?>
```